# HttpClient and FileUpload big files upload/download

Tags: java, file-io, file-upload

I am writing a small test desktop app and I want to make it upload (to Servlet) and download (from Servlet) binary files >=1Gb length. I am just studying the Apache lib and I want to test it. I couldn't find any useful (client/server) tutorial which demo the upload/download mechanism with `HttpClient` and `FileUpload`.

I need to see **both** project parts the client and server sides because I need to know how client options effect server request etc. I need to see their live code working interaction.

All examples I could find are not working or client side was not specified for server's example.

So I want you to advise me some code examples, snippets. Any useful comments are appreciated.

P.S.
 - Client: HttpClient
 - Servlet: FileUpload (apache common)

Andrew

Answer (score -1):

check this
http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-use-multipart-post-method-for-uploading.html

Comment: I've tried this example but it doesn't work with the lib I have installed :( I have HttpClient 4.1

Comment: This errors I get only

"MyTestApp.java": Error #: 704 : cannot access directory org\apache\commons\httpclient at line 29, column 1

Comment: I don't know why but 4.1 has this package org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod; empty ?

Comment: So the PostMethod class is out of the 4.1?